# Returning n columns from n to n table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having this configuration, relational model wise:

```
A --- * C * --- B
```

`C` is therefore the n-to-n table between `a` and `b`.

Given that `C` has the following fields: `aID, bID, cValue`

And `B` has the following: `bID, bName`

How can I select all entries in `A` with `n` columns for all `B` that applies with the `aID`?

For example, the select would return the following columns

```
aID - bName1 - bName2 - bName3
1   - cValue1 - cvalue2 - cvalue3
2   - cValue4 - cvalue5 - cvalue6
```

Since different entries in A may or may not match with all the entries in B, some of the column could be nulled.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL.  A SQL query has a fixed number of columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible with a single query.

The SQL language has a very strict requirement to know the number and types of columns at query compile time. Queries where the data determines the number or types of columns, such as with this question, are not possible. Even `SELECT *` queries can still get fixed column information from the table schema.

Instead, you have to do this in three steps:

1. Write a query to return data about the columns you want
2. Use the results of that query to generate a new query dynamically
3. Execute the dynamic SQL and return the results

Even then, it's usually considered better practice to pivot this data in your client system.

There may be one other possibility. If you can put a reasonable limitation on the number of A <=> B connections in advance, you can do a LEFT JOIN between A and B (via C) multiple times, once for each possible connection, where you end up potentially with a lot of NULL values in the results. It's also potentially a very wasteful query.